# How can I set the default column filter with DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am trying to give a the second column in our data table sorting from biggest to smallest/ I have tried the following without success.

```
  $(".one-table").dataTable({
           "bRetrieve": false,
          "bFilter": false,
          "iDisplayLength":4,
          "bLengthChange": false,
          "bJQueryUI": true,
     "bAutoWidth":false,
      "aoColumns": [
        { "asSorting": [ "asc" ], "aTargets": [ 2 ]},
        { "asSorting": [ "desc" ], "aTargets": [ 1 ]} ]
        });
```

Whilst this works for setting the default sorting direction, it does not allow us to sort the default column. I have also tried iDataSort

Datatables API says to use $(document).ready(function() {

```
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  // Sort immediately with columns 0 and 1
  oTable.fnSort( [ [0,'asc'], [1,'asc'] ] );
} );
```

But this just creates errors

The next version I tried

```
>   var clTable;
>               clTable =  $(".one-table").dataTable({       "bRetrieve": false,
>           "bFilter": false,
>           "iDisplayLength":4,
>           "bLengthChange": false,
>           "bJQueryUI": true 
>   
>         
>         });
>             clTable.fnSort( [ [1,'asc'] ] );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe not this :

```
clTable.fnSort( [ [1,'asc'] ] );
```

but this:

```
clTable.fnSort( [1,'asc'] );
```

Comment: thank you! Sorting by hand after creation is not what I was looking for but is more than adequate to the task!

Comment: @veeTrain you're welcome. You can already sort the result in your query :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, except that my users get to decide the order of the columns so I don't want to order my query by whatever column they select as 'first' when I can have the table just skip the 0th column (which I hide -- and which was being sorted upon any way) and sort on whatever is the first column instead.